# What's wrong with javascript (toFixed) method?

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code?

```
var result = 985.toFixed(2);
```

And the fix is:

```
var result = (985).toFixed(2);
```

I still want to know the reason. :)

Comment: It's Just a parser issue - the brackets make it easy for the parser to know the number token is complete, whereas a '.' could indicate there is a fractional part of the number.

Comment: you can just insert a space before the dot..

Comment: Or fully specify the number (remember, all numbers in js are floating point): `985.0.toFixed(2)`. This also avoids confusion on the part of the parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, the Javascript interpreter interprets the dot as a decimal point, because it's coming after a number.

Putting brackets around the number gets around this limitation.